# I want to connect to a Website using C with HTTP-Authentication

Tags: c, winsock

I want to connect to a single Website in my LAN which is using HTTP-Authentication using C with Winsock, to verify if a file is there.

How do I perform the Login-Part, is it possible to build the socket using a variable like:

```
char connectionstring[64];
connectionstring = "user:password@host/files/download";
```

or how do I have to build it correctly? Since I do not know if `connect()` will allow me the connection to the website and how do I retrieve the

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Success
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side for a basic primer on how that connection string should look like

Comment: Also, I suggest you use libcurl if you can, instead of crafting this by hand.

Comment: Do it by hand can be quite long, why do this in C ?
You can take a look here to have some http machine https://github.com/Intersec/lib-common/tree/master/src/net

Comment: @Ôrel suggesting a different language for a task is not always appropriate. There could be reasons out of their control for having to use C. The company I work for has a couple of big-name customers that dictate the language to use, for example. Or it could simply be a side project to learn C and WinAPI.

Comment: it in fact is a side-project to learn C and Winsock. :)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca my point is that to do a such task (that I have already done) you have to learn http (and this is not the easiest protocol) and learn socket management en C. When you start a question saying I have a connection string I want to check if a file is there ? I think it will be the hard way to do this in C starting from a socket.